# Replace select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to replace a select element. However, instead of replacing the select with id "Base" a new select is generated within that select with the same ID. The relevant parts of my code are below. What part do you think is generating the duplicate select? The problem can be seen at this site when searching. http://bahcalculator.org/nano/

```
<select class="base" id="Base" onChange="codeAddress2();">
    <option>Select State First...</option>
</select>

function getbases2(){
    var S=$('#search').val();
    $.post("getbases2.php", {S:S},
        function(data) {
            $('#Base').html(data);
        });
} 
//getbases2.php

$S=$_POST['S'];
$re=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM state_bases WHERE Base='$S' ");
$ro=mysql_fetch_assoc($re);
extract($ro);

echo "
     <select class='base' id='Base' onchange='codeAddress2();'>
         <option>Select base</option>
    ";

$re=mysql_query(" SELECT Base FROM state_bases WHERE State='$State' ORDER BY Base ASC");
while ($ro=mysql_fetch_assoc($re)){
    extract($ro);
    if ($Base!=""){
    echo "
        <option
        ";
        if ($Base=="$S"){ echo " selected='selected' ";}
            echo " 
            >$Base</option>
        ";
    }
}
echo "
    </select>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('#State').val('$State');
            codeAddress2();
    </script>
    ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.html()` call will update the content of your element: it inserts the 'data' inside the select.
You should use `$.replaceWith()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/.

Comment: Thanks. Wrapping in a div fixed my problem for now. I'll try to learn more about replaceWith() so I can implement that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's doing exactly what you are telling it - generate a `<select>` within #Base which is a `<select>`. Try surounding the top `<select>` with a `<div id="wrap-around"></div>` if you wish to replace it.